# In Vue js, the Json response object's username field shows null while it works perfect in the back-end

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have made a Rest API with Django Rest Framework, where one of the api endpoint provide the correct userinfo in JSON. The endpoint work perfectly when tested with SWagger or Postman, gives all fields and their respective values but when I request the same endpoint from the Vue.js frontend the response it gets is somehow became **username = null**

Serializer class for the view:

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = C_User
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'verified', 'is_active']
```

The response in Postman is

```
{
"email": "testuser1@gmail.com",
"username": "testuser1",
"verified": true,
"is_active": true
}
```

But the same endpoint gives different response in Vue.js app:
[username=null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sxZa.png)

Vuex settings in Vue.js is

**state**

```
state: {
status: '',
access_token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || '',
refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token') || '',
username: ''
```

},

**mutation to save username**

```
whoami(state, data){
  state.username = data
}
```

**action that commit the mutations**

```
cur_user({commit}){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/auth/me/', method: 'GET'})
    .then(resp => {
      const user_data = resp.data.username
      commit('whoami', user_data)
      console.log(resp.data)
      resolve(resp)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      commit('whoami', {username: 'guest'})
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

*I tried to store the whole object in the vuex state and then all the fields except username are ok but username field gets null again.*

Why the response sent from the back-end gets altered in front-end automatically or is there any plugins that takes the username field and makes it null. It will be very helpful if you explain the reason and give a solution for this occurred problem. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome, go to Network tab, click the request and have a look at the response. To answer your question: Vue doesn't alter the response. In fact, Vue doesn't handle requests, that's why you use Axios. And Axios doesn't alter the response either, unless you use an interceptor. But Axios doesn't have any default interceptors, You'd need to write one to have one.

Comment: @tao I have tried the dev tools network tab to request but nothing changed, also tried to include other fields with the back-end serializer, everything worked fine but the username field gets null value again and again. And yeah I used **axios response interceptors to refresh the JWT token** and those endpoints also works great having no issues.

Comment: Please post a https://codesandbox.io reproducing the behavior